# How to include a variable in a function - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, so I have a variable that contains some information that needs to go in a function. For example, if I have;

```
var apikey="123456789";

function foo() {
    $.getJSON('http://api.websiteexample.com/ + apikey');
}
```

I'm looking to add some information that is stored in a variable to the end of a website address when requestion JSON data.

Is there way I've done in the example correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below,

```
//Note the quotes moved -----------------v
$.getJSON('http://api.websiteexample.com/' + apikey);
```

When you have it inside quotes.. It would be considered as a `string`. You need to put it outside quotes for it to know it is an variable.

Comment: Is it possible to add another string after? So after `apikey`, I could continue the URL?

Comment: @user1658756 Yes, just append with `+` operator

Comment: Okay so it'd be `$.getJSON('http://api.websiteexample.com/' + apikey + 'foo');`. That'll appear as http://api.websiteexample.com/123456789foo, right?

Comment: @user1658756 exactly.. It should be like that.. you should try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way

```
var apikey="123456789";

function foo(key) {
    $.getJSON('http://api.websiteexample.com/ ' + key);
}

foo(apikey);
```

Comment: So you can pass the apikey as a parameter to the function. It can be called anything you want. It allows your function to be resuable because it will work the same way if your api key changes.